# Add OneLogin as an OIDC to IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I am currently setting up IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core Identity, and I am trying to integrate this with OneLogin OIDC.

I have my IdentityServer4 service setup and running.  I have added the Google scheme to this, so on my IdentityServer login page I have a login form and the Google login button.

I have created several client applications, an MVC app, a basic javascript app and also an Angular app.

With these clients I am able to authenticate against IdentityServer and get an access token, and then access a .NET Core WebAPI I have setup as an API scope.

My company uses OneLogin as our SSO, so I am trying to see if I can link IdentityServer to OneLogin.

In my IdentityServer Startup.cs ConfigureService method I have added the following

```
            services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                
                options.ClientId = "clientid";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OneLogin", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Authority = "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2";
                options.ClientId = "clientid";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });
```

I am able to view the following Provider Configuration from OneLogin for my corporate domain:

```
{
"acr_values_supported": ["onelogin:nist:level:1:re-auth"],
"authorization_endpoint": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2/auth",
"claims_parameter_supported": true,
"claims_supported": ["sub", "email", "preferred_username", "name", "updated_at", "given_name", "family_name", "locale", "groups", "params", "phone_number", "acr", "sid", "auth_time", "iss"],
"grant_types_supported": ["authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token", "client_credentials", "password"],
"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["HS256", "RS256", "PS256"],
"issuer": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2",
"jwks_uri": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2/certs",
"request_parameter_supported": false,
"request_uri_parameter_supported": false,
"response_modes_supported": ["form_post", "fragment", "query"],
"response_types_supported": ["code", "id_token token", "id_token"],
"scopes_supported": ["openid", "name", "profile", "groups", "email", "params", "phone"],
"subject_types_supported": ["public"],
"token_endpoint": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2/token",
"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post", "none"],
"userinfo_endpoint": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2/me",
"userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported": ["HS256", "RS256", "PS256"],
"code_challenge_methods_supported": ["S256"],
"introspection_endpoint": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2/token/introspection",
"introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post", "none"],
"revocation_endpoint": "https://companyname.onelogin.com/oidc/2/token/revocation",
"revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post", "none"],
"claim_types_supported": ["normal"]
```

}

I have a OneLogin developer account, and in there I have created a "OpenId Connect (OIDC)" application. Here I have the options to configure a Login URL and a Redirect URL.

I put the redirect URL as https://localhost:44361/signin-oidc, where localhost:44361 is my IdentityServer instance.  I Initially put localhost:4200/login as the login URL, which is the URL of my angular application.

When I navigate to my Angular app, I am directed to my IdentityServer login page as expected.  Here I have a button for "One Login".  I click this button, which does then take me to OneLogin, again as expected.  I enter my login credentials.  OneLogin then redirects me to https://localhost:44361/signin-oidc.  However, I receive the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'client authentication failed', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?  The OneLogin documentation doesn't seem to be very clear (no on screen help or tips when setting up the OIDC app).

I can't find any tutorials or documentation on IdentityServer4 and OneLogin, so I am wondering if what I want to achieve is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sods Law.

I managed to find a solution in this OneLogin blog post, 20 minutes after I posted my question.

https://www.onelogin.com/blog/how-to-use-openid-connect-authentication-with-dotnet-core

The step I was missing was creating a Custom Connector before creating my OIDC Application in OneLogin.

With that connector in place, I am able to authenticate and I am returned to my Angular SPA.